# System.String[] Split(Char[])' method unrecognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following data and i want to filter the data using  Linq to Entities, But i am getting the exception :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[]
>   Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

I have following data in the table

```
1           HPM,BKM     NULL        1,2,3
2           HPM,BKM     L1,L2       1,2
3           KK,CC,ZZ,PP             3,4
```

And i am writing the following code

```
var criteria_1="1";

var criteria_2="HPM,"

var Col4 = DB.Letter_Logic.Where(m => m.Col1.Equals(criteria_1)
            && m.Col2.Split(',').Contains(criteria_2)).ToList();
```

It should be give me values 1,2,3 as my result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because there is no way to translate Split(Char[]) into a SQL expression. You would need to do a ToList() first then perform your split operation, but beware that this will bring  back more results to your computer before filtering them out using your split expression:

```
var Col4 = DB.Letter_Logic.Where(m => m.Col1.Equals(criteria_1))
                          .ToList()
                          .Where(m => m.Col2.Split(',').Contains(criteria_2))
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting this exception while using the above. Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context. However i am able to get the result using some other method as {1,2,3) how can i use inner join this to another table to bring back related data. Thanks once again for your time.