# Split and join in LINQ to Sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I do split and join on a Linq Query.

```
from job in snwe.Jobs
join city in snwe.Cities 
on job.Location.Split(',').First() equals city.CityId.ToString()
```

Error thrown

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[]
>   Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

NB: `Cities` is such a large Table.

Comment: is CityId an integer?

Comment: yes cityId is an integer

Comment: How large is *large*?

Comment: Please create an extra N:N table to store this relation. The person taking over your project will be gratefull

Comment: @MichaelD Can't change DB. Its already designed and the whole project have to be changed

Comment: @RGraham Most of the cities over the world included.

Comment: In that case Linq is not the right tool for the job. Use an SP.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to Entities cannot translate the C# code into SQL. You can cast the intermediate results to lists and then do your operations, which might be costly ([System.String[] Split(Char[])' method unrecognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576078/system-string-splitchar-method-unrecognized)).

You could try to optimize your query to not use the `Split()` function.